# Quartz.net job scheduling

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

how does Quartz.net work in the background. suppose i have created a job which would get triggered next year. so what's happening in the background for one year. . Is there a process or thread which keeps running continuously for one year.does it implement timer in the background?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the Quartz scheduler. As long as the scheduler is running, Quartz will keep track of schedules and start jobs according to their schedule. But as Quartz is a library hosted inside your application, you have to start the Quartz scheduler yourself.

In scenarios where you don't have an application that is always active (like a website), you have to find some way to let the Quartz scheduler run independent of that (for instance in a scheduler service dedicated to running your jobs). I've found a few references to using Quartz.net in ASP.Net projects, but I have no personal experience with running Quartz within a website. I don't know how Quartz would react to IIS shutting down or reusing the application pool your site is running in. But if your job can handle being aborted, it may be a viable option. You'd have to start the scheduler in the `Application_Start` event in your `Global` class.

No matter how you run Quartz, you will want to use a non-volatile job store. Quartz can store the scheduled jobs in memory, but you'd have to re-schedule all jobs after each application start. So it is highly recommended to use another job store that can persist jobs between application restarts.

The Quartz.net [quick-start tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html) has bits of code to show you how to use Quartz in your application.

Comment: maybe i could do this in global.asax file so that whenever application restarts scheduler is back with its jobs . would that help?

Comment: https://quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.1/pdf/Quartz_Scheduler_Developer_Guide.pdf

Comment: seems like you can use Quartz in global.asyx, but I don't know how reliable it works given that IIS may re-use your app-pool whenever it sees fit. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net